# I want to send file more than 20mb to amazon s3

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

It's not possible in sfdc to send files more than 12 mb because we have an asynchronous heap size limit of 12 MB. but still I don't want to use any app exchange app. so how can I achieve this. and in S3 file object, I am able to upload 20 MB

Answer (score 0):

Reverse it. Pull instead of push.

Send some notification and have a program running on AWS that would pull the document by ContentVersion's ID or something. (REST API call to `/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/put-id-here/VersionData`)

You could send session id in the notification or have the credentials in the program.

Comment: Not really, I don't have intellectual property rights to what I did in the past... And it entirely depends on how you'd build that listener in AWS (or really any other "agent" program you can think of, as long as you have way to pull from sf and push to s3). You might be fine even with old school outbound messages or https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/external-services/get-started-with-external-services, no apex code needed. If needs coding - it'd be basic HTTP callout from apex, lots of examples? and about 3rd party programs logging in to sf - same.

Comment: consider tagging the question better to attract some S3 gurus, maybe there's some smart built-in way. And maybe post in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ too