# I Want to send file more than 12 mb size from salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I Want to send file more than 12 mb size from salesforce to external system without using any appexchange apps, any suggestions

Comment: What have you tried yourself since asking https://stackoverflow.com/q/68392669/313628

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to send file more than 20mb to amazon s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392669/i-want-to-send-file-more-than-20mb-to-amazon-s3)

Comment: There isn't a better answer than the one you already got; you can't do this in Apex.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to my knowledge it is not possible as the apex has a heap size limit of 12 MB per transaction. So if you try to send the data more than the size 12 MB, then the transactions are likely to get failed. Try compressing the file.

Thanks